# reuse same class in different class hierarchies

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

Sometimes your callback interface has more than one callback method, each for different kind of event. One example is `org.xml.sax.ContentHandler` which has `startElement()`, `characters()`, etc.

Sometimes you want to have a set of reusable handlers and chain them in arbitrary order. In Java it's solved by the delegate design pattern: you create an abstract class that implements each method of the interface, see:

```
javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate
org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl
com.common.util.xml.DelegatingContentHandler
```

Then you extend this abstract class overriding only the needed methods, then in runtime you create the chain of handlers passing the next delegate to the constructor of the previous delegate.

I was wondering if `declare parents` of AspectJ would allow to create such chains statically. I don't want to manually create a delegator class for an interface and I don't want to create the chains in runtime.

Here's what I've done so far: there are 3 classes: A,B,C that print their name and then call `super`. For each possible pair I'd like to create classes: AB,AC,BC that have the features their pair of classes.

The desired output of my program:

```
ASupport
BSupport
===============
BSupport
CSupport
===============
ASupport
CSupport
===============
```

The program that doesn't compile:

```
package org.foo;

public class AnAspect {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AB().handle(null);
        new BC().handle(null);
        new AC().handle(null);
    }

}

aspect AnAspect1 {
    declare parents : AB extends ASupport;

    // can only insert a class into hierarchy, but org.foo.BSupport is not a subtype of org.foo.CSupport
    declare parents : ASupport extends BSupport;
}

aspect AnAspect2 {
    declare parents : BC extends BSupport;
    declare parents : BSupport extends CSupport;
}

aspect AnAspect3 {
    declare parents : AC extends ASupport;
    declare parents : ASupport extends CSupport;
}

class BC extends MyCallback {

}

class AC extends MyCallback {

}

class AB extends MyCallback {

}

class ASupport extends MyCallback {

    @Override
    public void handle(Object o) {
        System.out.println("ASupport");
        super.handle(o);
    }

}

class BSupport extends MyCallback {

    @Override
    public void handle(Object o) {
        System.out.println("BSupport");
        super.handle(o);
    }

}

class CSupport extends MyCallback {

    @Override
    public void handle(Object o) {
        System.out.println("CSupport");
        super.handle(o);
    }

}

abstract class MyCallback {

    public void handle(Object o) {
        System.out.println("===============");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course you cannot overcome JVM limitations via AspectJ and make `ASupport` extend both `BSupport` and `CSupport`. Each class must have single superclass (or none, in which case it implicitly inherits from `Object`). Also the variant `declare parents : CSupport extends ASupport;` would not work because it would lead to a circular hierachy, which is of course forbidden because it makes no logical sense.

You also seem to misunderstand how a delegator pattern works:

- It does **not** work via inheritance and `super()` calls but
- by means of an internal member pointing to the delegate (if any, the first member in the chain does not have a delegate, of course).

Let us just take a look at two of the classes you mentioned in your question, shall we?

```java
package javax.xml.stream.util;

// (...)

public class StreamReaderDelegate implements XMLStreamReader {
  private XMLStreamReader reader;

  /**
   * Construct an empty filter with no parent.
   */
  public StreamReaderDelegate(){}

  /**
   * Construct an filter with the specified parent.
   * @param reader the parent
   */
  public StreamReaderDelegate(XMLStreamReader reader) {
    this.reader = reader;
  }

  // (...)

}
```

```java
package org.xml.sax.helpers;

// (...)

public class XMLFilterImpl
  implements XMLFilter, EntityResolver, DTDHandler, ContentHandler, ErrorHandler
{
  private XMLReader parent = null;

  /**
   * Construct an empty XML filter, with no parent.
   * (...)
   */
  public XMLFilterImpl() {
    super();
  }

  /**
   * Construct an XML filter with the specified parent.
   * (...)
   */
  public XMLFilterImpl(XMLReader parent) {
    super();
    setParent(parent);
  }

  /**
   * Set the parent reader.
   * (...)
   */
  public void setParent(XMLReader parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
  }

   // (...)
}
```

See? In both cases there is no inheritance but delegation. The `super()` calls are unrelated to the delegation pattern, they just make sure that the super class constructor is called as it should be. What we have here is just a flexible list of objects, each one pointing to its delegate, similar to a linked list. This is a much more flexible approach than your idea to cast everything into a fixed set of classes.

IMO your approach is trying to solve a problem which does not really exist. It is an example of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898). Feel free ask follow-up questions if I can help you any further with this. Tell me **what** you want to achieve and not **how** you believe it should be done.

Comment: `It does not work via inheritance and super()` I know. However classes that extend delegators still have to call super.

Comment: So? Where is the need for your solution? Imagine you have 10 different handlers. If you want to create convenience classes of all possible pairs you already have 45 combinations (or actually 90 if the order of delegates is important which often it is in filtering situations). 120/240 triples, 210/420 quadruples etc. Why would you want to create that many "convenience classes"? Nothing is convenient about that. Just chain them via delegate pattern and be happy. I do love AOP, especially AspectJ, but this is not a good case to use it. Don't re-invent the wheel, use the existing one and be happy.

Comment: How about accepting and upvoting my answer? I both explained that what you want is technically impossible in the JVM because your idea involves multiple inheritance and also told you why the delegation pattern works so well in this situation. So if there are no follow-up questions, I would appreciate if we could close this issue.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but I rather wait for other opinions. Maybe there's a way to create copies of a class with different ancestors or use `around/proceed` instead of `override/super`